# Why can't I access the /data directory with ADB on my Samsung Vibrant?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, adb, root-access

I used Simply Honey before and everything was okay. However, when I flash to a Stock 2.2 ROM, I cannot access the `/data` directory from `adb`. I am sure the phone is totally rooted because I have the Superuser icon in my apps menu and I can open the `/data` directory in Root Explorer. Why can't I access `/data` from `adb` as well?

Comment: What's the error?  Are you escalating the adb shell to root?

Comment: no, just when use adb shell to go into data directory, it says "don`t have the permission"

Answer (score 3):

You need to escalate the shell, since /data requires root permissions to access.  After running `adb shell`, run `su` before running `cd /data`.  The prompt should change from `$` to `#` if it works.

Comment: but i can`t run su in adb shell.

Comment: @ufo Why not? You can run it if you have it.  [Example use](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Magic_Root_Access).